# How to see which JVM an executable Jar is using?

Tags: java, dll, parameters, jar, jvm

The project uses a dll which has to be copied to JVM_HOME/bin directory. From the IDE the application works fine (the dll is copied in JAVA_HOME/jre/bin) but when I try to run the application directly, the dll is not found.

Edit:

1. It is not PATH env variable.
2. Running it with double click results in "dll not found", but when calling with java -jar myJar.jar the application works fine.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the project does, what the .dll is, etc?

Comment: Trying to read/write to the searial port; the .dll is rxtxSerial.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Windows task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>), you can open "View" -> "Select columns..." -> "Image path name". There are other nice options there, too, such as "Command Line" which also shows command line arguments.

Or you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), where you can double-click a process to see image path, command line arguments, and much more.

Comment: Thanks! I actually had the dll at that location but was a 64 bit version (as that used in the JVM from the IDE); but the JVM called by the executable jar is a 32 bit version and thus needs a 32bit dll.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows 2k3 or above, you can use the `where` command, as in `where java` to see which java is on the path.

If you're using a unix variant, you can use the `which` command, as in `which java`.

Comment: Besides the one in JAVA_HOME, it shows C:\Windows\System32; after copying the dll there still doesn't work.